# Macbook Pro 8.1 Keyboard Backlight on Ubuntu 11.04 With KDE

Tags: unity, kde, gdm, macbook, kdm

Can anyone tell me how to enable my keyboard's backlight? It works fine using gdm and Unity. I recently installed kde 4.6.5 and started using kdm, everything works fine as in unity, only my keyboard's backlight on the Macbookpro 8.1 does not come on. 
Kindly assist.
regards.

Answer (score 2):

Install [pommed [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pommed) and make it start automatically on reboot.